# Insert text in textarea using python and selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, textarea

I want to insert text in the text area using python and selenium .Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you try something? Share your current code

Comment: Use, this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372336/how-can-i-add-a-text-in-textarea-by-selenium-python?noredirect=1#comment85748053_49372336